# Some characters in OpenStreetMap display as rectangles

Tags: openstreetmap, tiles, mapnik

I installed tileserver based on the instructions provided [here](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/) for Ubuntu 14.04 using this [approach](https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto) . All fonts and Shapefiles were downloaded and installed from INSTALL.md.

The tileserver works well, but I have rectangles instead of some characters (in Chinese, Japanese, Korean, Indian, some African countries and cities names).

There is only debug information in log:

```
//initialization, no errors
//...
//loading fonts, no errors
//all fonts are loaded
DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 10, number 3
DEBUG: Got incoming request with protocol version 2
DEBUG: Got command RenderPrio fd(10) xml(default), z(7), x(113), y(51), mime(image/png), options()
//and so on.
```

This part of log of tile generating process (China tiles).

Comment: Anything relevant in the logs?

Comment: It might be an encoding issue. Openstreetmap uses UTF-8. I`m not sure if this has to be set in Postgres or Mapnik explicitely.

Comment: I've seen this before. Are you using a Unicode font for your labels? Arial Unicode MS is often used, as in [this example](https://www.mapbox.com/help/getting-started-cartocss/#font-variables) from Mapbox.

Comment: AndreJ, I installed utf-8 in postgre database creation process. And there is utf-8 as default in mapnik configuration.

Comment: kontextify, I am using dejavu-fonts-ttf for labels.

Comment: Looks like [dejavu-fonts](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Main_Page) does not support Asian alphabets.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load a font with support for Chinese, Japanese, Korean, Devanagari, Tamil, etc. Try Droid Sans Fallback (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droid_fonts). See also the Noto font family: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noto_fonts.

Comment: [GNU Unifont](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Unifont) also has good unicode coverage, although it's a bitmap font so results are 'blocky'.